# Telegram bot: How can I add buttons in a private chat for the recipient

Tags: automation, telegram

please I need your help

I have a food delivery website,where customers order food from restaurants and we deliver them

I want a bot to simplify the work for my operator.

The bot shall show the list of restaurants ,when I click on the list of restaurants it redirects to the specific restaurant owner chat room,where my operator and the restaurant owner can chat,the restaurant owner will get two buttons or options to accept or deny the order.I need your help for creating this bot,I tried a lot and I'm unsuccessful inthis

Atleast how to add buttons to the chat so that the restaurant owner will react to the accept or deny

Please give me an answer ,it will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You may use reply_markup with as an option to the message  in order to get buttons

```
  bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Do you want to accept order?', {
      parse_mode: 'MarkdownV2',
 reply_markup: {
        inline_keyboard: [
          [
            {
              text: 'Yes',
              callback_data: 'yes'
            },
            {
              text: 'No',
              callback_data: 'no'
            }
          ]
        ]
```